# Reduced memory options for lots of Duktape contexts

Tags: duktape

I'm trying to configure a light-weight full-featured JavaScript engine such that I can have tens of thousands of independent contexts simultaneously.  Each context is doing very little (mostly event processing, light string manipulation, custom timers, etc.) and doesn't require much heap storage, but needs to be independent from the others.  Using Duktape, if I allocate 20,000 contexts in x64, I get upwards of 1.6GB of memory utilized before doing much processing, or about 80KB each.  As another data point, if I use SpiderMonkey 1.7.0, 20,000 runs me about 1.4GB or about 70KB... nearly the same.  I've played with several of the optimizations Duktape has to offer but it doesn't seem to impact this usage.

So the question is, is there a way to get the per-context memory utilization down to the 4KB (or less) range per context?

Note: yes I know SpiderMonkey 1.7.0 isn't really full-featured, but it is for the sake of what I'm trying to do and doesn't have the JIT complexity that I don't want and don't need from later engines, V8, etc.  Hence the look at Duktape as an alternative.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The minimum startup cost for a new global environment is almost entirely caused by built-in objects and their properties: there are roughly 70 built-in objects with 250 function properties and 90 value properties. You can reduce this by deleting unnecessary built-ins and/or built-in properties.

One thing you can do is enable DUK_OPT_LIGHTFUNC_BUILTINS, which replaces most built-in functions with a more lightweight function representation, reducing built-in object count. This has some side effects such as built-in functions having a less readable autogenerated "name" property.

If your contexts are small, another thing you can do is to use "pointer compression" which causes Duktape to represent heap pointers with 16-bit values. You need to provide macros to encode/decode pointers to/from this representation. This approach only works if the maximum size of an individual Duktape heap is ~256kB (assuming align-by-4 allocations). The feature was developed for embedded low memory 32-bit platforms though, so it may not work ideally on 64-bit environments (master branch has a few fixes for pointer compression and 64-bit platforms, so use master if you try this).

Reaching 4 kB/context won't be possible with any of these measures - there are simply too many built-in objects and properties for that. Getting to that memory amount per context would only be possible if you shared global objects for multiple scripts, which may or may not be possible depending on the isolation and threading needs of your scripts.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer.  A quick test of `DUK_OPT_LIGHTFUNC_BUILTINS` showed about 52KB/context in my test case as opposed to 80KB so that's definitely a step in the right direction.  It was also 22% faster (presumably gains in context create/destroy).  I'll stay away from pointer compression since even though most context heaps will be small, some will not and I won't know which are which in advance.  I'll look into the built-ins (46 in my version?) but it appears most will be needed (math, json, prototype/constructors, etc.).  Are there any in particular that are extra-big? Thanks

Comment: It basically comes down to the number of objects and the number of properties in these objects. Each property takes about the same space because the value is either a primitive (e.g. a number) or a reference to a built-in function. A function reference takes the same amount of memory as a plain number value with DUK_OPT_LIGHTFUNC_BUILTINS enabled. The difference in the built-in count is probably due to ArrayBuffer support in master branch which wasn't yet in Duktape 1.2 release.

Comment: If the contexts are short lived you could also try removing reference counting and rely on mark-and-sweep alone (DUK_OPT_NO_REFERENCE_COUNTING). This will reduce object header size a little bit, at the cost of a little more variable memory usage and finalizers that don't run immediately but rather when the objects are collected.

Comment: Thanks again... I experimented a little with DUK_OPT_NO_REFERENCE_COUNTING, including forcing a GC after each context's use (which is bursty), but it seems that although slightly faster, it actually increased the heap marginally.

Answer (score 1):

As a quick update on this question: Duktape 1.5.0 will have a config option to place built-in strings and objects into ROM (read only data section): https://github.com/svaarala/duktape/pull/559. The same read only strings and objects will be shared across all Duktape heaps and contexts without using any RAM. Once the feature is finalized it'll also be possible to put your own strings and builtins into the read only data section so that they won't consume any RAM per heap/context.

With this change it's possible to reach ~4 kB startup RAM usage on a 32-bit target and ~8 kB on a 64-bit target.

Comment: any thoughts on when 1.5 will be stable/released?  thanks.

Comment: April looks possible for a 1.5 release. The ROM built-in changes are already functional in master.